# Как решить проблему с ошибкой session_start()?

Tags: php

У меня есть два файла в проекте первый файл это - .htaccess и в нём данное содержание

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(js|mp3|mp4|html|css|php|png|jpg|svg|exe|mkv|avi)$

RewriteRule .* index.php
```

второй файл index.php и в нём содержится

```
<?php

session_start();

?>
```

и в итоге у меня ошибка

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at newProject\index.php:1) in newProject\index.php on line 3
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: у вас скорее всего пробел или непечатаемый символ перед открывающимся тегом php

Comment: или `<?php`  не на первой строке

Comment: Спасибо я уже решил проблему суть была в кодировке файла я просто удалил файл и создал новый и затем поместил код внутрь файлов.

Comment: не в самой кодировке а в BOM надо полагать все же